# Create/Update Postgresql table via Microsoft SSIS package

Tags: sql, postgresql, ssis

I want to do the following two things:

- Create a table "Lite AC" with two columns (id, lite_ac) in a Postgresql database via Microsoft SSIS package
- Update that newly created table via another SSIS package

I want to use that table in order to integrate it into a `WHERE SUBSTRING IN (Lite AC)` statement.

I am using pgAdmin to connect with that Postgresql database. I know how I can export data from Postgreql via an SSIS package so all the drivers should be installed, but no idea how to do that the other way round.

Is that possible?

Comment: Isn't this a matter of choosing `Source` and `Destination`?

Comment: I don't know, this is no man's land for me. So, shall I just try it as I do it when exporting data from the PSQL DB? Also, what sort of rights are required on the Postgres side to be able to create such a table?

Comment: Also as the DB in Postgres contains several schemes, how do I specify under which scheme the table is created then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not have Postgres installed.

You need two connection managers. One for source and the other for destination. 
In your case destination is Postgres DB. In order to test out, you may use a `Flat File Connection` to insert set of sample data from a .txt file. Following tutorial emphasizes on Login credentials to Postgres DB.

1. [Install the relevant drivers (32bit and 62bit accordingly)](http://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/msi/)
2. [Follow this tutorial](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2619/export-data-from-postgres-to-sql-server-using-ssis/)

Once you are able to connect to Postgres DB via SSIS and rows are inserted into the DB using .txt file - try to add a SQL Scripting Task to be executed after Data Flow Task, so to update the records in the new table.